# How to add Tor Services in My Java Application

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, torsocks

I am working online application and while working , some of my ip are banned .
After that i came to know about Tor and i want to know how to add the tor services in java applications.

Please do needful on this.

Answer (score 3):

You could try and use [**jtorctl**](https://github.com/guardianproject/jtorctl) which is a

> A Java library for controlling a Tor instance via its control port. It
> is used in the Android app Orbot as well as others.

[**Orchid**](https://subgraph.com/orchid/index.en.html)

> Orchid is a Tor client implementation and library written in pure Java.
>
> It was written from the Tor specification documents, which are available [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/documentation.html.en).
>
> Orchid runs on Java 5+ and the Android devices.

There are also other solutions written but it is written Python such as:

[**Stem**](https://stem.torproject.org/api.html)

> Stem is a Python controller library that you can use to interact with
> Tor. With it you can write scripts and applications with capabilities
> similar arm.

[**txtorcon**](https://txtorcon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> txtorcon is a Twisted-based Python asynchronous controller library for
> Tor, following control-spec. This would be of interest to anyone
> wishing to write event-based software in Python that talks to (and/or
> launches) a Tor program.

They seems to be more comprehensive than `jtorctl`. If the Java libraries doesn't work, maybe you can integrate these Python libraries into your Java project using [**Jython**](https://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/whatis.html). Goodluck!

Source: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/523/13768

Comment: What would be the best way for a java client to connect to to netowrk without needing to install the tor browser first ?

Comment: @sudhir I believe I have already listed the best options that doesn't require the Tor Browser Bundle above.

Comment: I've added Orchid to the list, it's a pure java implementation of a Tor client.

Comment: Thanks for that reference! I have added that API to the linked source's community wiki while crediting to you there, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Tor - from the application point of view - is *just a proxy and DNS server*, so use SOCKS, transparent proxy and DNS *as usually on Java*